# Entity Framework 4.0 - Many to Many relationship is inserting records on the left side of the mapping, not only in the relationship table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I have a ManyToMany relationship in Entity Framework with POCOS.

I have a Table called Transaction which has a TransactionId column and some other columns and this is the entity i want to insert, one Table called Reason which is a catalog table that has a ReasonId and a ReasonDescription column, I also have one table called Transaction_Reason to save the relationship, this table has 2 columns called ReasonId and TransactionId with foreing keys to their respective tables.

In my Transation configuration for EF I have the following in the constructor:

```
             base.HasKey(t => new { t.TransactionId }).HasMany(c => c.Reasons).WithMany(r => r.Transactions)
            .Map(t =>
            {
                t.MapRightKey("ReasonId");
                t.MapLeftKey("TransactionId");
                t.ToTable("Transaction_Reason");
            });
```

The relationship is done correctly, I get records inserted in my Transaction_ReasonTable, but whenever I check the Reasons table I also get records created here, when this should only be a catalog table.

Heres my insertion code:

```
                if (reasons != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in reasons)
                    {
                        Reason reason = _reasonReopository.Find(item);

                        transaction.Reasons.Add(reason);

                    }
                }

                transaction = this._repository.Create(transaction);
                this._repository.Commit();
```

I only want to have records inserted in my Transaction Table which is the record I'm creating in my Save method and in the Transaction_Reason table where the relationship is saved, not in my Reason catalog table.

Does anybody have any idea of how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason :) is: you fetch `reason` instances by `_reasonReopository.Find(item)`, which uses a context instance of its own. The `transaction` is added to another context by `this._repository.Create(transaction)`, but this context does not "know" the `reason` instances in the `transaction` and kindly inserts them as new items.

You can fix this in two ways:

- Fetch the `reason` instances in the same context as the `transaction`.
- Attach the `reason` instances to the `Reasons` DbSet in the context of the `transaction`

I would prefer the first option, but since you seem to have repositories per entity option 2 probably works best in your case. However, I would consider refactoring your repositories to repositories per "aggregate", where an aggregate is a number of logically related entities. Drawing the borders between aggregates can be subjective, though.